# What is the meaning of these? "$g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [-5,-2]$" and "$h:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$"

Tags: calculus, notation

> What is the meaning of the notation in the following?
>
> a) $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [-5,-2]$
>
> b) $h:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$

a) I'm thinking means domain is set to all real values, and codomain is set to point (or between $[-5,-2]$)

b) domain is set to all real values, codomain is set to all real values in second dimension.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: $g$ is a function whose domain and codomain, as you correctly stated, are the real numbers and $[-5, -2]$ respectively. Your interpretation is correct.

Comment: Domain and codomain are to be interpreted in loose sense though, actual domain of definition and range of the function (sometimes also called domain and codomain) are to be included in left and right sets resp.